# How to derive the ADM form of this relativistic Hamiltonian?

Tags: general-relativity, action

The action for a general relativistic particle should be:

$$S=\int d\tau\int d^3x \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu}\dfrac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \dfrac{dx^\nu}{d\tau} \,\delta^3(x-y)$$

where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the 4-metric. How to derive from this action the ADM form of the Hamiltonian?

The momenta should be $\pi^\mu=\sqrt{-g} \dfrac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$, so  after the Legendre transform I get something like this:

$$\int d\tau\int d^3x \dfrac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\pi_\mu - \left[ \dfrac{\pi^\mu\pi_\mu}{\sqrt{-g}} \right]$$
I do not know how to precede from this point.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the action you should be using? If $x$ is the particle's path, it cannot be integrated over, and also this looks neither like the Nambu-Goto nor the Polyakov action for a point particle.